# Remove Clicked Element and then apply css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have placed a div on top of image. On click event of div I am removing the div and then applying CSS to the image, but CSS is not getting applied .. below is the code

```
$('#one').live('click', function() {
    $('#one').remove();
    var selglobe= $('#' + globe);
    selglobe.addClass('abc');
    selglobe.css("border","double");
});
```

tried this,
HTML code:

```
$('#one').live('click', function() {
$('#one').remove();
console.log('HTML Globe value is ' + globe);
flipIt(this);
});
```

JQUERY:

```
function flipIt(obj){
 if(status==1 )
{
alert('If'+globe);
console.log('JS Globe Value is'+globe);
var $selglobe = $('#' + globe);
 $('#id11').addClass('imgnew');
 $('#id12').addClass('transition');
 $selglobe.addClass('anam');
 $selglobe.css("border", "double");
 $selglobe.css("border-color", "yellow");
 }
```

Have a look at this jsFiddle provided by the comments:
http://jsfiddle.net/jF4mh

Comment: post your markup and what is getting in the `globe` variable. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Mind that the 'live' function in jQuery is deprecated use on() if you can. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Which CSS doesn't apply? the `abc` class or `border` property?

Comment: Also, guess you're better of using a class name instead of an id, using `.on()/.live()` tells me you're expecting elements to be added via ajax/other sources. There may be an id conflict in those cases

Comment: @ badZoke globe variable contains image id..

Comment: @NK123 post the HTML please, still see only jQuery code.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: To help you better you could make a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: m trying .ok i ll do.

Comment: `console.log(selglobe.length)` insert that after `var selglobe= $('#' + globe);` & let us know what's getting printed?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jF4mh/ is working fine for me, which probably means either you have the wrong id by mistake, or the value of `globe` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: fiddle working fine for me also.

Comment: which jquery version you are using?.. 'live' has been removed from version 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Check your jquery version. You are using 'live' function which has been removed from jquery 1.9. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining globe?

Anyway I would be using the on click, and just removing the element at the end.

```
$('#one').on('click', function() {
    $('#one').remove();
    var selglobe= $('#' + globe);
    selglobe.addClass('abc');
    selglobe.css("border","double");
});
```